# Cloud providers and proprietary data

Tags: internet, data-ownership, data-storage, data-protection

I have read the terms and conditions of my cloud service and they "reserve the right to monitor abusive or offensive usage", but I would like to know if they can spy on my proprietary data and use or sell it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it depends entirely on the terms of an actual agreement, and is too localised.

Comment: I do not know if it's off topic in this forum but let me point out that I posted originally a question on "meta" asking where that kind of question should be  asked and the only constructive suggestion was "law". FYI

Comment: There are some questions for which there exists no Stack Exchange site that the question is on-topic for. Law is the closest for this question; that doesn't make the question on-topic on Law SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they can do with your data depends entirely on the TOS. There might be a provision that allows them to peer into your data for analytic purposes; there might even be a provision allowing them to copy and sell your data. Your baseline protection is [copyright law](https://law.stackexchange.com/tags/copyright/info): in order to copy your data (basically, do anything with it other than store it and make a backup of the server), you need to grant them permission. In searching for that information, look expansively at such things as "privacy policy", for example the Gmail TOS is itself fairly minimal ("you agree that Google can use such data in accordance with our privacy policies"), because it refers you to their [privacy policy](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/) document. [Box](https://www.box.com/legal/termsofservice) says

> You hereby grant Box and its contractors the right to transmit, use
>   and disclose Content posted on the Service solely to the extent
>   necessary to provide the Service, as otherwise permitted by these
>   Terms, or to comply with any request of a governmental or regulatory
>   body (including subpoenas or court orders), as otherwise required by
>   law, or to respond to an emergency which Box believes in good faith
>   requires Box to disclose information to assist in preventing the death
>   or serious bodily injury of any person.

So you have to read the fine print.